# ListView setSelection - selecciona item pero no cambia el background

Tags: java, android, android-listview

Tengo un problema, al querer seleccionar un item despues de llenar el listview, este no usa el drawable que tengo de background

```
<item
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="@color/colorTouch"/>
<item
    android:state_selected="false"
    android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

Este es mi xml que uso para el listview

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/selecter">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="#000"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/artista_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="#000"/>
```

Necesito seleccionar el item y que use el background, este es mi codigo

```
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
listView.setSelection(pocision);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(listListener);
View v = getViewByPosition(pocision,listView);
v.setSelected(true);
```

Este es el metodo que uso getViewByPosition

```
private View getViewByPosition(int pos, ListView listView) {
    final int firstListItemPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + listView.getChildCount() - 1;

    if (pos < firstListItemPosition || pos > lastListItemPosition ) {
        return listView.getAdapter().getView(pos, null, listView);
    } else {
        final int childIndex = pos - firstListItemPosition;
        return listView.getChildAt(childIndex);
    }
}
```

El item queda seleccionado pero no usa el background que necesito, en cambio cuando lo selecciono con el evento si funciona:

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        view.setSelected(true);

    }
```

Este es mi adaptador:

```
public class SongAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

public SongAdapter(Context context){
    this.context = context;
    ListaCanciones listaCanciones = new ListaCanciones();

    lista = listaCanciones.getLista();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return lista.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return lista.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.song_item, parent, false);
    }

    TextView txtTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title_item);
    TextView txtArtista = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.artista_item);

    Cancion cancion = (Cancion)getItem(position);

    txtTitle.setText(cancion.getNombre());
    txtArtista.setText(cancion.getAutor());

    return convertView;
}


private List<Cancion> lista;
private Context context;
```

}

Cuando llamo el evento el background si cambia, ¿Cual es mi error?

Comment: Usas un ArrayAdapter propio?

Comment: Si, uso BaseAdapter

Comment: Ahi puse el adaptador para que lo veas

Answer (score 0):

Tu selector tiene solo un estado el cual activa el color, y este es al seleccionarlo, por esa razón no se mantiene el color:

```
<item
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="@color/colorTouch"/>
```

Comment: ¿Osea que debo ponerle el color del estado cuando sea falso?

Comment: Si deseas que cambie en otro estado así debe ser.

Comment: Ya lo hice y sigue con el mismo problema

Comment: Pero que relizaste???, edita tu pregunta

Comment: Mira lo que adicione al selector